# NuGet version constraints doesn't work

Tags: c#-4.0, nuget, versioning, nuget-package, build-agent

I have Project which references from NuGet repository Module of version 1.0.0.0.

For some time Module versions are changed to 1.1.0.0, 1.1.0.1, 1.1.1.0, 1.1.5.0, 1.2.0.0, 1.2.1.0. And my Project supports just 1.1.X.X versions set. And the latest version NuGet should upgrade Project reference is 1.1.5.0, but NuGet suggests 1.2.1.0.

Due this article: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning I need to modify packages.config of my Project and set 'allowedVersions' attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Module" version="1.0.0.0" allowedVersions="[1.1,1.2)" />
</packages>
```

Does NuGet supports constraints on minor versions?
NuGet version is 2.7.41101.299

Answer (score 1):

can you please provide more details about your project type and the packages installed? or a simplified repro app is fine, which will help us diagnosis the issue.

Btw, the latest version of NuGet is 2.7.2, which can be downloaded at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget. Please see if your issue still reproes with the latest version. Thanks!